# Firebase Rules not working: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firebase Rules are not working properly. I am able to read data, however am unable to create!

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow public read access, but only content owners can write
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true
        allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_id;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author_id;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i think you are unable to change the rules due to your role in the project. check if you have the admin rule in in project users.

Comment: @abdelhedihlel just checked...I am the owner of the project!

Comment: Rules on their own don't do anything yet. Please edit your question to show the minimal code with which any of us can reproduce the problem against these rules, and be sure to show in your code that it matches the rules, i.e. that you're setting the `author_id` field to the UID of the current user.